# Data structure for representing sparse tensor?

Tags: c++, sparse-array

What is an appropriate data structure to represent a sparse tesnor in C++?
The first option that comes to mind is a `boost::unordered_map` since it allows operations like fast setting and retrieval of an an element like below:

```
A(i,j,k,l) = 5
```

However, I would also like to be able to do contractions over a single index, which would involve summation over one of the indices

```
C(i,j,k,m) = A(i,j,k,l)*B(l,m)
```

How easy would it be to implement this operator with a `boost::unordered_map`? Is there a more appropriate data structure?

Comment: Is in sparse in each dimension?
you could implement wrapper around array of or map of a ublas::sparse_matrix.

Answer (score 0):

There are tensor libraries available, like:

```
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/tensor.aspx
```

and

```
http://cadadr.org/fm/package/ftensor.html
```

Any issue with those?  You'd get more tensor operations that way over using a map.

Comment: The libraries that you mention all use dense tensors, and I need to use sparse tensors as the dimensions of my tensors are too large to be represented efficiently as a dense tensor.